# E: Unable to locate package mysql-server

Tags: package-management, mysql

After an import of another database, the mysql root@localhost was not taking.  I know that it worked because the data got imported and I was able to change the password of the user that was imported using root.  However, after a day running, I tried to login as root and I couldn't.  I tried a bunch of other web suggestions, etc., but none worked.  I was running mysql-server-5.7.  Anyway, since I knew that I just needed to recover the data, I said let me reinstall it and I would be on my way.  WEll, I was wrong.  For some reason, I was not able to uninstall it, nor install it back.  Finding a few web suggestions, I am now at this state where when I type,

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

I get.

```
root@GBRTEF01LX005:/home/bzadmin# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server
```

Any other suggestions?  Thanks.

josé

Comment: Please add output of  `apt-cache policy mysql-server` to your question.

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried  `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` and no go.

Comment: `apt-cache policy mysql-server`<br/>
`N: Unable to locate package mysql-server`

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you have? Try `sudo add-apt-repository main`.

Comment: 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu

Comment: >WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'<br/>  
<br/>    
>WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'<br/>  
<br/>    
>'main' distribution component enabled for all sources.<br/>

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: NAME="Ubuntu"  
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question.

Comment: deb [link]http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main

Comment: trying  to  see  something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73608/discussion-between-jicman-and-n0rbert).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is absolutely broken.

Try to fill it with the following contents:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This did it.  I am wondering why this happened.  I appreciate your help.  mysql-server is installed.  Thanks again.  By the way, how do I enter a new line here?  I tried two spaces and that didn't work.

Comment: If I understand correctly new lines in comments are not supported.