# MySQL 5.7 installation implications after upgrade to Bionic Beaver

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, updates, mysql

I have seen `deb` entries to set in `source.list` file for which `apt-get` can operate.

[Updating source.list in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009157/821177)

Likewise, as part of my UbuntuVM upgrade I had updated source.list later through some web dashboard for `Bionic Beaver` and did `curl` or `copy paste` as instructed, however before in order to do certain activities I ran the following command which was fruitful.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Then, I had installed MySQL 8 (5.8). Now I have to go back to 5.7. Now following command is basically failing,

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

as we already marked our box for upgrade with `dist-upgrade -y` for `apt-get`

Now what I have to do myself, so I can install MySQL 5.7 using `apt-get`

MySQL 8 which is 5.8, that I had uninstalled using,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now while trying to install MySQL 5.7 I am getting following error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.7 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
                    Depends: mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Nothing had gone messy so far,

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Now someone let me know how I can bring back MySQL 5.7

Here is feasibility status for MySQL 5.7 installation using `apt-cache policy` if have `xenial` in `sources.list`

```
$ apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-5.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

If I have `Bionic Beaver` in `sources.list`, I get 500

```
$ apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-5.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.7.21-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Basically I tried executing this once,

```
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.7`.

Comment: While installing/upgrading to MySQL 8 I used debian variant, I don't know, based on some references I set `sources.list` to `trusty`, before that I was not able to install because of one library file dependency which wasn't there in Ubuntu, but this one only made to progress `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe`

Comment: Managed to installed it in the `Box`. I made mix & match of operations. Basically I had removed one module which was sticky using `sudo apt-get remove --purge`. Hence onwards `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` had worked as I set version `5.7` for `sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb`

Comment: In addition to this, I also reset-ted my mysql password and followed this answer feed, written by me,- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351720/mysql-fails-to-start/50792506#50792506 . Hope this helps. I think someone corrupted my mysql database. Anyway it's a good learning. Earlier I was not even unaware of `dpkg` command usage.

Comment: Before I gone for this upgrade `MySQL`, I had a problem that, `mysqld` - **MySQL Server Daemon** was not starting. So I gone for **MySQL upgrade** rather, that's when I written this feed. I was completely gone blank first of all. Moreover the newer MySQL didn't work, because in parallel I have to update my JDBC driver as well considering the application in which I was involving. Anyway it's good learning as I state.